# ruby parse array to hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, parsing, hash

a array like this:

```
a = ["<root>", 
"<products>", 
"<product>", 
"<id>", "1", "</id>",
"<name>", "name1", "</name>", 
"</product>",
"<product>", 
"<id>", "2", "</id>",
"<name>", "name2", "</name>", 
"</product>",
"</products>", 
"</root>"]
```

and a hash like this:

```
b = {
"products" => {
  "product" => [
     {"id" => "1", "name" => "name1"},
     {"id" => "2", "name" => "name2"}
   ]
  }
}
```

How to get this hash `c` out of `a` and `b` ：

```
c = {
"products" => {
  "product" => [
     {"id" => "1", "name" => "name1", "id_index" => 4, "name_index" => 7},
     {"id" => "2", "name" => "name2", "id_index" => 12, "name_index" => 15}
   ]
  }
}
```

4, 7, 12, 15 are indexes of "1", "name1", "2", "name2"  in the array `a`.

Comment: Before you got that array, did the data start in some sort of XML form?  Are you trying to parse XML into JSON?

Comment: no xml, i hope get this hash c out of a and b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it would look like:

```
c = {'products' => {'product' => b['products']['product']
  .map{|o| o.merge({'id_index' => a.index(o['id']), 'name_index' => a.index("name#{o['id']}")})}}}
```